# How and Where Should I create a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to manipulate my `.htaccess` file but I cant find it. I've checked my www folder and theres nothing in it, by the way **I'm using Xammp and Apache**. **Can anyone teach me how to create a `.htaccess` file so I can increase my `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`**. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see one, then just create one in the directory you want those PHP values to take effect. Name it "`.htaccess`" and add the following lines (with the appropriate values):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 16M
```